# How do I plot a .csv file as a bar graph correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image][image]I have imported, successfully, a .csv file with film information and have begun the process of creating a bar graph to show each film's gross, with the gross as x-axis and the film title as the y-axis. I'm not sure why the code below is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

table = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/*****/Desktop/Python/Fav_Movies.csv')

plt.bar(x=np.arange(0,5),height=table['monies'])
plt.title("FILMS")
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,23), table['title'], rotation=50)
plt.xlabel("TITLE")
plt.ylabel("GROSS")
plt.show()
```

the error I get is

> "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
>   shape."

I have looked it up but I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the top two lines of your csv file? Also try running it without any of the title/xylabeltick stuff.

Comment: looks like you want a plt.barh, not a plt.bar. Your y-values will be table.title, your x-values will be table.monies. Here's the basic model: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace your plt.bar line with:

```
plt.barh(table.title, table.monies, align='center')
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. One question though, what's with the blurry text at the bottom? The picture is added to the original post.

Comment: Delete your xticks line.  Really, if you want more control over labels, you've got to generate separate subplots for the figure and the axis.